# Confused by ArrayList Initialization

Tags: java, arraylist, depth-first-search

I am confused by the line `res.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(temp));`. Could you please tell me why it's wrong if I just use `res.add(temp)`?

```
public void dfs(int[] nums, int index, List<List<Integer>> res, List<Integer> temp) {
    res.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(temp));
    for(int i = index; i < nums.length; i++) {
        temp.add(nums[i]);
        dfs(nums, i + 1, res, temp);
        temp.remove(temp.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are initializing an `ArrayList` around another list, there is nothing _wrong_ with this, per se.  Maybe you did intend to use `addAll()`.

Comment: java not confused..you only confused

Comment: Could you also show the calling code for these two methods?  It isn't clear how you intend to use `res` after calling the methods.

Comment: If you didn't create a copy, all the elements in `res` would point to the same list. The point is to capture `temp` in a specific state so it's not affected by further modification.

Comment: No, not addAll(). The code is used to find subsets of a arrary, if I use res.add(temp) instead of res.add(new ArrayList(temp)), what it returns is just [[],[],[],[],[]...]

Comment: @shmosel  Thanks buddy!

Comment: minor formatting - deleting unnecesary code

Comment: Guys please add the solution as the answer, if it solves the problem. Don't leave it as just a comment..Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `temp` is an object reference to an object in memory, in this case a list of `Integers`. By calling the `remove` method on `temp` you actually alter the `list` object that `temp` points to in memory. So after the `for` loop you might get an empty list while trying to use `temp`.

Using `new ArrayList<Integer>(temp)` actually creates a new `list of Integers` object in memory that the original `temp` reference has no relations with, in other words it doesn't reference that new `list of Integer`object. So that's basically a new `list of Integers`.